# Fiery hair/head

Tags: minifigures, clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I thought I saw a head with flames on it. (Maybe it was a hair piece?).  I looked for 'flame' and 'fire' on BrickLink but couldn't find it.

Here's a [custom minifigure](https://www.flickr.com/photos/133756918@N07/19186272263) that may be using the hair piece I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find a few pieces with flames on BrickLink:

[Minifigure, Headgear Head Cover, Flame Head Piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15404)

[image]

[Minifigure, Head Modified Alien with Trans Orange Flaming Hair and Reddish Brown Face, Yellow Eyes and Headband Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26990pb03)

[image]

[Minifigure, Head Modified Alien with Trans Orange Flaming Hair and Skull with Yellow Eyes Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26990pb02)

[image]

[Minifigure, Head Modified Alien with Trans-Orange Flaming Hair and Pumpkin Jack O' Lantern Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26990pb01)

[image]

Your picture seem to be showing a non-LEGO piece, which is similar to [Minifigure, Hair Spiked Top, Plain](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62699). Also a comment on Flickr for this picture suggest: "It appears to be a trans-red knockoff piece with the goggles painted on"